# React routing in ES5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using "react@15.0.2" and "react-router@3.0.0".

I have this minimal example and I can't make it work:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h1>Test</h1>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Test}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I know that `<Test/>` is OK because `ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, ...)` works fine.

gulp compiles it, but the page is not displayed and the console says:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at invariant (bundle.js:41330)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (bundle.js:39575)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:28233)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:28160)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (bundle.js:35008)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:35674)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:33795)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js:38439)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:33816)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (bundle.js:38439)
```

---

Edit: the index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <!--ALL REACT CODE-->
      <div id="app"></div>
       <!--ALL REACT CODE-->

      <script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: simple demo https://codepen.io/pshrmn/pen/YZXZqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the `<Router>` element being passed as first param into `render()` in parenthesis:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<h1>Test</h1>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Test}/>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

It may just be parsing issue.

Also try updating your `require` statement for `react-router`. Adding a `.Router` to end of the statement per [react-router installation instructions](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#installation) for non ES6 builds.

Hopefully that helps!

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
```

Comment: It doesn't work either... After your suggestion, I've also tried to put it in the same line, but it didn't work either: `ReactDOM.render(<Router><Route path="/" component={Home}/></Router>,document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: It may be issue with Home component that's being retrieved/injected, please share that code. I'd also share your main entry point, HTML element with id `app`. Otherwise it may be a build issue (webpack).

Comment: I've tested it and <Home/> works fine. I've updated the original post with an even more minimal example, and added the index.htm as you asked. If it is a webpack build issue, how could I attack the problem? I unfortunately wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Try updating your require statement for `react-router` by adding a `.Router` to the end. This would be in line with the [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#installation) installation documentation. See the updated answer. Hopefully the added parenthesis around the `Router` component and that added part to require help.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. There were other errors, could you please update your answer in case someone else stumbles upon this question?: I also had to change `var Route = require('react-router).Route; var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;`, and finally `ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory}> ... `. Thanks for your help (sorry I can't upvote with my reputation of 1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes like the above comment mentioned, the answers dont specify the browser history part.

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var SchoolsList = require("./components/SchoolsList.jsx");
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

var _question = schoolsStore.getQuestion();

function render(){
    //console.log(_question);
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={SchoolsList} question={_question.question} activeIndex={_question.activeIndex} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("container"));
}

render();
```